# Mono.Cecil invoke generic type constructor

Tags: .net, generics, mono.cecil

Using Mono.Cecil I have injected a type looking something like this:

```
internal class InjectedDelegateCommand<TParameter> : ICommand {
    // Fields
    private readonly Predicate<TParameter> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<TParameter> _execute;

    // Events
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    // Methods
    public InjectedDelegateCommand(Action<TParameter> execute) : this(execute, null){}

    public InjectedDelegateCommand(Action<TParameter> execute, Predicate<TParameter> canExecute) {
        if (execute == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }
        this._execute = execute;
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
        return ((this._canExecute == null) || this._canExecute((TParameter) parameter));
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        this._execute((TParameter) parameter);
    }
}
```

I now need to inject some code to initialize a property of a class with this command type i.e.:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ViewModel(){
        SubmitCommand = new InjectedDelegateCommand<string>(
            new Action<string>(OnSubmit)
            , new Predicate<string>(CanSubmit));
    } 

    public ICommand SubmitCommand {get; set;}
    public void OnSubmit(string parameter){}
    public bool CanSubmit(string parameter) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to properly implement the constructor call in cecil.

Can anyone help? I'm not interested in what IL needs to be generated but rather how to get the proper MethodReference for the constructor to implement these lines:

```
        SubmitCommand = new InjectedDelegateCommand<string>(
            new Action<string>(OnSubmit)
            , new Predicate<string>(CanSubmit));
```

**EDIT** - Including what I've tried.

I've tried writing the method below to get me the constructor I want to use but the generics is wrong:

```
private MethodReference GetConstructorResolved(MethodReference commandConstructor, MethodDefinition method)
{
    var parameterType = method.HasParameters
        ? method.Parameters[0].ParameterType
        : Assets.TypeReferences.Object;

    var commandType = commandConstructor.DeclaringType;
    bool isGeneric = commandType.HasGenericParameters;
    if (commandType.HasGenericParameters)
    {
        var commandTypeResolved = commandConstructor.DeclaringType.MakeGenericInstanceType(parameterType);
        commandType = commandTypeResolved;
        var resolvedConstructor =
            commandType.GetElementType()
                .Resolve()
                .GetConstructors()
                .First(c => c.Parameters.Count == commandConstructor.Parameters.Count);
        commandConstructor = resolvedConstructor;
    }

    if (isGeneric)
    {
        if (method.HasParameters)
        {
            commandConstructor =
                commandConstructor.MakeHostInstanceGeneric(method.Parameters[0].ParameterType);
        }
        else
        {
            commandConstructor = commandConstructor.MakeHostInstanceGeneric(Assets.TypeReferences.Object);
        }
    }
    return commandConstructor;
}
```

Where MakeHostGeneric comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16433452/203499

I end up with IL looking like the following (**Note** in this example I'm trying to just invoke the single argument constructor, since if I can figure that out I can figure out 2 arguments) :

```
IL_0013: ldftn instance void WpfMvvmSample.ViewModel::Submit(string)
IL_0019: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<string>::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_001e: newobj instance void class 'InjectedDelegateCommand'<string>::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<!0>)
IL_0023: call instance void WpfMvvmSample.ViewModel::set_SubmitCommand(class [PresentationCore]System.Windows.Input.ICommand)
```

Comment: I've updated the post with what I've tried.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: Yes. Still having this issue.